# Max Heap finding kth smallest elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, heap

Assignment:

> You have an unsorted list of elements, in our case integers, and you must find the kth smallest element in that list. The obvious idea is of course to sort the list in ascending order and return the kth smallest element. This should be done in O(N Log N).

I am trying to find the kth smallest element which I use a Max Heap for. As I understand I need to sort the Array in increasing order and return when I get the kth smallest element. If I understand correctly a Max Heap is best to use to sort the Array in an increasing order, but a Min Heap for finding the kth smallest element. This is where don't get it. How can I sort the Array in ascending order and also return the kth min? I am having a problem finding out how to get the kth smallest element if I use a Max Heap as it would not make sense to wait until the Array is fully sorted, then traverse it with a for loop and get the kth smallest, as that would not make HeapSort O(N log N) since it would require another for loop to traverse the Array. And if I use a Min heap it would be descending order.

This is how the Max Heap is sorting the Array in increasing order:

> Max Heap is made: [10, 9, 8, 5, 1, 8, 3, 5, 5, 1]
>
> [9, 5, 8, 5, 1, 8, 3, 1, 5, 10]
>
> [8, 5, 8, 5, 1, 5, 3, 1, 9, 10]
>
> [8, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 8, 9, 10]
>
> [5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 8, 8, 9, 10]
>
> [5, 3, 5, 1, 1, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10]
>
> [5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10]
>
> [3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10]
>
> [1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10]
>
> [1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10]

I can't figure out how to get the kth smallest. I though about a Min Heap because the smallest is always index 0, but that is used for making a decreasing array?

This is my method which is a Heapsort. It calls buildHeap, and then does the sorting.

```
//Find kth smallest element-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private int[] findKthSmallestElement(int[] arr, int kthElement) {
    buildheap(arr);
    System.out.println("Max Heap is made: " + Arrays.toString(arr));

    if(kthElement > arr.length){
        System.out.println("Number does not exist.");
        return arr;
    }
    else if(kthElement == arr.length){
        System.out.println(kthElement + " st/nd/th smallest element number" + " is: " + arr[0]);
        return arr;
    }

    heapSize = arr.length - 1;

    for(int i = heapSize; i > 0; i--) {

        swapCurrentNodeWithMaxChild(arr,0, i);

        heapSize--;

        percolateDown(arr, 0,heapSize);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to find the kth smallest element in a Max Heap. As I understand I need to sort the Array in increasing order and return when I get the kth smallest element.

No, to find the k-th smalles element in a Max Heap, we just need to extract `n-k` elements from the Max Heap. No sorting is needed.

> that would not make HeapSort O(N log N) since it would require another for loop to traverse the Array.

We don't need to sort the array, but as a side note one loop to traverse the Array does not change anything, since `O(N log N + N) == O(N log N)`

Comment: But the exercise tells me that I need to sort the Array in increasing order? Also, the traversing of the Array will be in the Heapsort method, which is inside the buildHeap method, so it will be a for loop nested in the for loop in the buildHeap method which is N^2.

Comment: It wasn’t in the original post, now I see that you’ve edited it. Sure, the Max Heap is the way to go then. You simply can’t use Min Heap to sort an array in ascending order. Max Heap sort is a O(n log n), accessing k-th element is a constant time op.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If `k` is small relative to heap size `N`, then retrieving of k-th smallest from **Max** Heap is rather long task - it requires `O((N-k)*logN)~O(N*logN)` time for `(N-k)` extractions of top elements.

To address problem itself - to get k-smallest from unsorted list, you don't need full sorting, don't need to build full heap.

Variant 1) Get `k` first elements, build **max**-heap **only for these k elements**. Traverse all other elements. If current item is smaller than heap top, remove top and insert current item. At the end heap top contains k-smallest. Complexity is `N*logK`.

I suppose that this variant is preferable if you are studying heaps now.

Variant 2) Perform QuickSelect algorithm (average complexity is linear but the worst case might occur)

Comment: So it would make sense to use a Min Heap and sort the array in a decreasing order?

Comment: Min heap is better if k is small. But what is real problem? How sorting is related to extracting of k-smallest?

Comment: I will put my assignment question in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need explicitly implement the algorithms or you can use Java APIs?
If you can use APIs it could be easily done with Arrays.sort(). I'm omitting the conditions testing k < arr.lenght for the sake of simplicity.

```
public void khtElement(k){
    int[] elements = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 5, 1, 8, 3, 5, 5, 1};

    Arrays.sort(elements);
    System.out.println(elements[k-1]);
}
```

Comment: I can't use java APIs

Comment: And do you need to make a Max Heap as a start point? I mean, you could sort the array in ascending order in O(n log n) and then take the kht element in O(1)

Comment: The assignment says nothing about needing to use a max heap, but I suppose that is what I need since it is max heap that sorts in increasing order? I know I can sort in ascending order in O n log n and then extract, but that is exactly my question, how do I extract the kth smallest?

Comment: Well, if O(N log N) must be assured in the worst case then forget what I said. But if it's an averaged O(N log N) then you can use quicksort. Once the array is fully ordered, accessing kth element by index is O(1)

Comment: Worst case should be O n log n :)